# MySQL+PHP+Flash+as3 How to save into a mySql data from a Flash AS3 2d RPG game in OFFLINE programming.?

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3, flash, localhost, offline

It's my first time to ask online about my programming problem and I hope I can get feed backs as soon as possible. Me and my partner are working on a project of doing a 2D RPG game using FLASH CS5.5, AS3, PHP(Dreamweaver cs5.5) and Mysql(xampp). I would like to know if there's any way that wwe can create the game and connect it to mysql where we can save and retrieve data after a game is played and save it in the players status so that when the player  plays again, he can have the last status of his game to continue. We want it to be an OFFLINE game and anywhere i search in the net, all of the tips are for online games. PLease help us. Thank you.

Comment: The tipps for online games and MySQL Connections are the same as for offline games and MySQL Connections, aren't they? Use `localhost` as host and all should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

## Assuming the game is mostly written in ActionScript 3

In order to save data on the an SQL server you need to pass the data from AS3 to PHP and insert it into the server.

To do this, you will need to become familiar with AS3's [JSON library](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html). There are numerous ways to do this, including the popular [as3codelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib), but the JSON library is built in and is much simpler than it first appears.

I would explain it all, but this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-flash-login-system-using-php-and-mysql-part-1--active-5147) will get you familiar with it.

P.S: Like others have said, you will want to test this locally so make sure you know how to perform basic SQL queries and run PHP scripts using XAMPP. If you do not, [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=running%20php%20in%20xamp%20tutorial) should help

Answer (score 0):

If you only want this to run locally (i.e. a user has their own set of data), why don't you just use a [`SharedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html)?

This lets you save data to the users machine very easily and much more efficiently.